# Looking for a list of Minecraft mob heights and hitboxes

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What are the mob's height and hitboxes? I just want to have the list of all of them.  Thanks if you guys can help :)

Comment: To whoever closed this: Why did someone feel the need to close the question? It is perfectly focused and has some pretty good answers. If you don't know the answer to a question let someone else answer instead of voting to close this, you can survive without that 5 reputation you might have gotten

Answer (score 1):

Following [Technical Minecraft Wikia](https://technical-minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Entity_Hitbox_Sizes):

| Entity | Base Size | Height |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Baby Turtle | 0.50 | 0.12 |
| Baby Rabbit | 0.2 | 0.25 |
| Cod | 0.5 | 0.3 |
| Baby Chicken | 0.2 | 0.35 |
| Baby Ocelot/Cat | 0.3 | 0.35 |
| Pufferfish (PuffState | 0) | 0.32 |
| Tropical Fish | 0.5 | 0.4 |
| Salmon | 0.7 | 0.4 |
| Turtle | 1.1 | 0.4 |
| Baby Wolf | 0.3 | 0.425 |
| Baby Pig | 0.45 | 0.45 |
| Rabbit | 0.4 | 0.5 |
| Pufferfish (PuffState 1) | 0.5 | 0.5 |
| Dolphin | 0.9 | 0.6 |
| Baby Panda | 0.65 | 0.625 |
| Baby Sheep | 0.45 | 0.675 |
| Chicken | 0.4 | 0.7 |
| Baby Cow/Mooshroom | 0.45 | 0.7 |
| Baby Polar Bear | 0.65 | 0.7 |
| Ocelot/Cat | 0.6 | 0.7 |
| Pufferfish (PuffState 2) | 0.7 | 0.7 |
| Baby Horses (all) | 0.6982 | 0.8 |
| Wolf/Dog | 0.6 | 0.85 |
| Pig | 0.9 | 0.9 |
| Baby Llama | 0.45 | 0.9375 |
| Panda | 1.3 | 1.25 |
| Sheep | 0.9 | 1.3 |
| Cow/Mooshroom | 0.9 | 1.4 |
| Polar Bear | 1.3 | 1.4 |
| Horse (all) | 1.3964 | 1.6 |
| Llama | 0.9 | 1.875 |
| Ravager | 1.95 | 2.2 |
| Endermite/Silverfish | 0.4 | 0.3 |
| Cave Spider | 0.7 | 0.5 |
| Phantom | 0.8 | 0.5 |
| Small Slime/Magma Cube | 0.51 | 0.51 |
| Vex | 0.4 | 0.8 |
| Guardian | 0.85 | 0.85 |
| Spider | 1.4 | 0.9 |
| Baby Zombie/Husk/Drowned | 0.3 | 0.975 |
| Shulker | 1 | 1 / 1.2069 |
| Medium Slime/Magma Cube | 1.02 | 1.02 |
| Creeper | 0.6 | 1.7 |
| Blaze | 0.6 | 1.8 |
| Zombie / Evoker / Villager / Husk / Witch / Vindicator / Illusioner / Drowned / Pigman / Villager / Pillager | 0.6 | 1.95 |
| Skeleton/Stray | 0.6 | 1.99 |
| Elder Guardian (Out of water) | 2 | 2 |
| Elder Guardian (In water) | 0.9975 | 0.9975 |
| Large Slime/Magma Cube | 2.04 | 2.04 |
| Wither Skeleton | 0.7 | 2.4 |
| Enderman | 0.6 | 2.9 |
| Wither | 0.9 | 3.5 |
| Ghast | 4 | 4 |
| Giant | 3.6 | 11.7 |
| Ender Dragon | 16 | 8 (special) |
| Squid | 0.8 | 0.8 |
| Bat/Parrot | 0.5 | 0.9 |
| Snow Golem | 0.7 | 1.9 |
| Iron Golem | 1.4 | 2.7 |
| Minecart | 0.98 | 0.7 |
| Boat (Out of Water) | 1.375 | 0.455 |
| Boat (In Water) | 1.375 | 0.5625 |
| Armor Stand | 0.5 | 1.975 |
| Falling Block | 0.98 | 0.98 |
| Xp Orb | 0.5 | 0.5 |
| Item | 0.25 | 0.25 |
| Ender Crystal | 2 | 2 |
| Player | 0.6 | 1.8 |
| Player (while sneaking) | 0.6 | 1.5 |

Comment: Thanks for your help